# Camel logging every line of stack trace on OctaneSdkException

Tags: java

I have a problem with camel logs; it is on a particular exception. Every time com.impinj.octane.OctaneSdkException is thrown camel starts to timestamp every single line of the stack trace.

```
2019-07-31 17:28:42,435 ERROR [stderr] (default task-12) com.acme.exception.ProcessManagerException: com.impinj.octane.OctaneSdkException: Error connecting to the reader (192.118.219.210) : Failed to get the session.
2019-07-31 17:28:42,439 ERROR [stderr] (default task-12)    at com.acme.kernel.Process.manager.ProcessManager.startProcess(ProcessManager.java:79)
2019-07-31 17:28:42,439 ERROR [stderr] (default task-12)    at com.acme.kernel.Process.manager.ProcessManager.startProcess(ProcessManager.java:47)
2019-07-31 17:28:42,439 ERROR [stderr] (default task-12)    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor175.invoke(Unknown Source)
2019-07-31 17:28:42,439 ERROR [stderr] (default task-12)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2019-07-31 17:28:42,439 ERROR [stderr] (default task-12)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

It always happens with this exception and no others. What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. It was a use of the standard error, so the use of:

```
e.printStackTrace()
```

Instead, I've used a

```
logger.error(e)
```

and everything just worked like a charm.